# Writing BASIC interpreter in java - loops and ifs

Tags: java, interpreter, basic

This paper: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/345888/How-to-write-a-simple-interpreter-in-JavaScript helped me greatly in terms of engineering parsing and write instructions, however it does not explain how to write loops and ifs. Can you point me to some papers about that? While adding predefined functions, etc. is easy, especially since my BASIC dialect will be very oldschool one with mandatory line numbers, requirement for using LET to set variables, etc. and very fixed syntax (i.e. no ':' to separate instructions, only one instruction per line, no whitespaces allowed for parameter separation so 10 LET variable,value is valid, but 10 LET variable, value is not)?

On second thought maybe ifs will be easy, but there's still problem on how to do for..next loop (my interpreter won't use whiles/do..whiles, only oldschool gotos/gosubs).

Comment: maybe you can check out the [interpreter pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/interpreter-pattern.html)

Comment: There is *no point at all* in implementing an AST-walking interpreter for a general-purpose language like Basic. Compile your basic to some flat representation first (e.g., a bytecode), or even straight into JVM. It is much easier and cleaner than an AST interpretation.

Comment: SK-logic - that may end with security errors. No, I prefer perfectly sandboxed interpreter which doesn't have access to cammands other than ones I want it to give.

Answer (score 0):

To implement `GOTO`, you need a way to modify the `i` variable (usually called the *program counter*) in `evaluate()`. One way would be modifying `parseNode` to return an object instead of simple value:

```
// ...evaluate()...
var result = parseNode(parseTree[i]);
if (typeof result.newI !== undefined) {
    i = result.newI;
}
if (typeof result.value !== "undefined") {
    output += value + "\n";
}
// ...parseNode....
else if (node.type === "goto") {
    return {newI : node.value};
}
```

Implementing `IF` would be simpler, something like this (if the condition is in `node.args`):

```
else if (node.type === "if") {
    if (parseNode(node.args).value != 0) {
        return parseNode(node.value);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this implements multiple statements per `IF` well, but your dialect doesn't either.

Comment: I know that. I've said that I'll have most problems with loops like for..next. But thanks for your input.